# Why was this question put on hold?

Tags: support, status-completed, reopen-request

Yesterday, I had asked this question: [What features are available in Windows 8 Single Language?](https://superuser.com/questions/625875/what-features-are-available-in-windows-8-single-language)

It instantly gathered a lot of downvotes, and later was put on hold, citing:

> "This question is not about computer hardware or software, within the
>   scope defined in the help center."

I fail to understand how it is not about software. 
I'm asking about features of a specific edition of an Windows Operating System. Windows 8 Single Language Edition is an Operating system, which is software.

Or is by convention the meaning of software something different on Super User?

Comment: While it is "shoping for an OS" like question. I support your idea that it is informative, interesting, valid, and useful for others to find when searching the web. It is not spammy, or list inducing. It can have a very specific single answer. I am ok with it. I am only a tiny aspect of a whole community, that decides things based on the community.

Comment: It was probably nuked because it *looks* like a simple google question. In the future, perhaps, you could reference what you've found vs what you're looking for. Link to resources that show it exists and resources that don't include it in the matrix.

Comment: @Raystafarian: If someone felt that the answer was a simple google search away, they should have googled it to verify that it was in fact was so. Just assuming that it is a search away, when it is not, is shoddy voting & unfair. As far as showing my research, yes I agree in principle. But in practice, I don't think it is possible to show that I have found nothing.

Comment: But you had found that the version exists and you had found that it wasn't included in the documentation that (exists) you found. Simply citing a starting point *might* deter the votes that assume it's a lazy question, if that's what happened.

Comment: @DevdattaTengshe - I did a Google search, and did find results, and did post my results as a comment to Dave Rook's answer. I also voted based on the results I found. I also posted official documentation pointing out `Windows 8 SL` is Windows 8 Core with single language pack.  You wanted to know the reason your question and thus I explained it.  I don't agree with the lock, the question is a valid question, just could have been answered yourself.